# Incorrect syntax near 'AS' when trying to create type in Sql Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using Sql Server 2012

I'm trying to create a type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.tempStores AS TABLE
(Store INT)
GO
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
```

As I did my research, it looks totally fine and should work, but it does not.

Does anyone has any idea on that issue?

Comment: I'm guessing either you need a `;` after `INT)` OR your lacking permissions to create types in DBO schema. OR the `dbo.` is unnecessary. Using [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526(v=sql.105).aspx) as an example

Comment: This works in SQL Server 2008. Are you sure it hasn't been created already? And are you sure you have permissions to create types?

Comment: I'm an owner, I also tried to do it with and without ;

Comment: SELECT @@VERSION.  What do you get back?

Comment: Hm... why do I have 2005 in there, while the Help>About shows 2012?

Comment: Because you're connecting to a 2005 SQL server but your local tools are 2012.

Comment: I got it. I'm connected to 2005... Rick S, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Above it, add

```
USE yourdatabase

GO
```

Comment: @MikeStockdale This looks like an answer to me. It might not be the *right* answer, I have no idea (if you know it's wrong, a downvote would be called for) but as far as I can tell it does look like an attempt at an answer. Am I missing something else here?